# Parameter for 'Project to build' in Jenkins 'Trigger/call builds on other projects' job section?

Tags: jenkins

A Jenkins job is calling another job before calling itself using `Trigger/call builds on other projects` section. However, the option `Project to build` of that section currently is hard-coded. Does anyone know how to make it parameterized or whether it is even possible? I could not find any solution for the same. I've tried `Build With Parameters` and `Parameterized Trigger` plugins but still could not find how to solve the issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can use any of the main build parameters in the **Project to build** section.</strike>

If you have a parameter called `my-downstream-job`, use `${my-downstream-job}` under **Project to build** section (yes, even under Windows, you need to use the Linux variable names here, as most plugins work through Java variables)

Above, I was thinking about **Copy Artifacts** plugin. You are right, it doesn't work for **Parameterized Trigger** plugin.

If you don't have too many choices, you can construct the logic with **[Conditional Build Step](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin)** plugin. Use the "Strings match" or "Regular expression match" to test the value of the parameter, and trigger relevant builds based on that. Not pretty, but could work.

Comment: Yes I was trying this one. And in this case there is an error, validation like 'No such project '${my-downstream-job}'. Did you mean 'hardcoded_name_here'?' So I've checked option 'This build is parametrized' and as a Choice have added that variable 'my-downstream-job' with the values, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: I guess I got confused with "Copy Artifacts" plugin, as that allows parameters for the name. You are right... the "Parameterized Trigger" plugin does not accept parameters. If you don't have too many choices, you can try "Conditional Build" plugin. I will update the answer.